# Increase jUnit speed execution when using mockk

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, mockk

I am having some issue with my jUnit tests. They are running very slowly.

Context: I have around 100 unit tests that are taking more than 2 minutes to run!
[image]

I am mocking dependencies using [mockk](https://mockk.io/) library. I noticed that the one that I mock dependencies are the slowest. I understand that mocking object can take some time, but that is just too much. I must have something wrong...

Here is the "pseudo code" for one of my unit test class:

```
internal class MyClassImplTest {

    @get:Rule
    val coroutineTestRule: CoroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()

    @MockK
    lateinit var dependencie1: Dependencie1

    @MockK
    lateinit var dependencie2: Dependencie2

    lateinit var myClassImpl: MyClassImpl

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this)
        myClassImpl= MyClassImpl(
            FakeCoroutinesDispatcherProvider(coroutineTestRule.testDispatcher),
            dependencie1,
            dependencie2
        )
    }

    @Test
    fun `should not be null`() {
        assertNotNull(myClassImpl)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should do something`() = coroutineTestRule.runBlockingTest {
        //mock method call with coEvery {}

        val isConnected = myClassImpl.connect(options)

        assertFalse(isConnected)

        //verify method calls with coVerify {}

    }

    @Test
    fun `should do something else`() = coroutineTestRule.runBlockingTest {
        //mock method call with coEvery {}

        val isConnected = myClassImpl.connect(options)

        assertFalse(isConnected)

        //verify method calls with coVerify {}

    }

}
```

For instance, this one was the one that took longer in the image above (38s).

This is not deterministic. It is not always the same that is the slowest, but when I run all of them it takes always more than 2 minutes to run...

So what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you one hundred percent sure that your tests are independent, and there are not affecting each other?

Comment: @Ice Well, I always create a new instance of the class under test and mocks for each test... Not sure how I can debug if they are affecting each other... But something is strange, because today, it is taking around 30s to run the same tests, instead of the 2min. Nevertheless, I believe it is still a lot... Something is wrong but I dont know what...

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago. First try to look into your code, check timeouts, possible locks, because maybe something is not released when it should be, and waiting for 2 min timeout. If your implementation bases on some times values, check it also. Maybe if you are not releasing the connection in the proper way and it hangs till timeout. Hard to say more without diving into code. Let me know, when you find something, I will try to help.

Comment: @Ice I didnt find anything special... No time related operations. I am mocking most of the dependencies so I don't think it is related with some connection not being release... I use runBlockingTest coroutine builder to be able to use coroutines on my tests. Getting out of ideas... Could it be due to using mockk? The few class tests that I dont use mock are fast to run...

Comment: Did you try to run this test class separately? The results are still non-deterministic? Maybe other classes affect these tests.  Which version of mockk are you using? Look here https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/13, there are some comments about the slow pace of mockk, because of ByteBuddy.